# how to expand variables within a variable in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I got stuck at a problem where I need to expand a variable in another variable as follow :

```
var1=abc
var2=$var1/pqr
echo ${!var2}
```

Here I want output to be abc/pqr , but not getting it , please help.
and var2 value is like this only , I can't put it in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> a="abcd"
>> b='$a/xyz'
>> eval c="$b"

>> echo $b
   $a/xyz
>> echo $c
   abcd/xyz
```

Comment: `eval` is certainly not indicated here.

Comment: Even in such tiny examples it would be a good idea to teach people to use quotes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need de-referencing in this case:

```
$ var1=abc
$ var2=$var1/pqr
$ echo $var2
abc/pqr
```

You de-reference when you assign variable as the value without the `$` sigil. For example:

```
$ var1=abc/pqr
$ var2=var1
$ echo ${!var2}
abc/pqr
```

Comment: here I am getting output as below : echo $var2  :  o/p $var1/pqr

Comment: I am not using any kind of quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `!`.

```
var1=abc
var2=$var1/pqr
echo ${var2}
```

Note the curly braces are not necessary above, but they do not hurt either.